# React Native Jest - BABEL Reference Error

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I'm developing a revision application for a project at Uni and I've pretty much finished all the code but now that it's time for testing, I'm having some trouble setting up the testing environment for my React Native project. I keep getting this error no matter what I try. I'm pretty sure I've messed  up the configuration of some of the dependencies, but have been trying to get this to work for days and just feel like I need a second opinion and a fresh set of eyes.

This is the error message I keep receiving;

```js
● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\Users\Owner\Dropbox\Discrete Math Tutor App for FC2\Revision App\FC2 Revision App\src\tests\Main.test.js: Unknown option: base.configFile. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/ for more information about options.

    A common cause of this error is the presence of a configuration options object without the corresponding preset name. Example:

    Invalid:
      `{ presets: [{option: value}] }`
    Valid:
      `{ presets: [['presetName', {option: value}]] }`

    For more detailed information on preset configuration, please see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins#pluginpresets-options.

      at Logger.error (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/logger.js:41:11)
      at OptionManager.mergeOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:226:20)
      at OptionManager.init (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
      at File.initOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
      at new File (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
      at Pipeline.transform (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
```

This is my package.json file;

```js
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "build": "(cd android/ && ./gradlew assembleDebug)",
    "bundle-android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --sourcemap-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.map --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "adb": "^0.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.1",
    "firebase": "^5.5.8",
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-lineto": "^3.1.3",
    "react-mindmap": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-alarm": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-android-fullscreen-webview-video": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-calendar-events": "^1.6.4",
    "react-native-calendar-reminders": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-charts": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-dash": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-div": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-dropdown": "^0.0.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-flexi-radio-button": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.2.12",
    "react-native-picker-dropdown": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-prompt-android": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.10.9",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-system-notification": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-video": "^4.3.1",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-native": "^4.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.3",
    "test": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(react-native|my-project|react-native-button)/)"
  ]
}
```

This is my babel.config.js file;

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

And this is the test file;

```js
import React from 'react';
import 'react-native';
import { Main } from '../screens/Main.js';
import { shallow, mount, enzyme, configure } from 'enzyme';

const Adapter = require("enzyme-adapter-react-16");

enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test('Search snapshot test', () => {
 const component = shallow(<Main />);
 expect(component.change(10)).toBe(100);
});
```

I would appreciate any help/ constructive criticism (because I'm sure that my coding practice isn't the best)! :)